# Android textview inside progressbar

Tags: android, textview, progress-bar

I would make a textview inside progressbar in Android. I wrote this code :

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/hamlebar"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:maxHeight="65dp"
            android:scaleY="15"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oyunhamletv"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bartext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hamle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hamlebar"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hamlebar"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hamlebar"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hamlebar"

    />
```

But the text looks : https://i.hizliresim.com/6D4lY9.jpg

How I can make a good textview inside progressbar?

I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the drawables of the progressbar (maybe even to set the height to a specific dp number).

I did something like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/prog"
        android:progress="50"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="this is a test" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the prog.xml.

```
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#234"
                    android:centerColor="#234"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a24"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#144281"
                    android:centerColor="#0b1f3c"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#F6101d"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the progress doesn’t change with this code.